# sitecore Access denied error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I am using Sitecore 7.2 and have created many content items, everything is working fine except items in an "admin" folder.

When I try to access Blog admin from admin folder, I get `noaccess` error, I have checked permissions and they look fine. The following string is added to the URL and redirect to the my 404 page.

```
?item=%2f**noaccess**&user=extranet%5cAnonymous&site=website
```

I have inherited this project from a different developer, so I am trying to figure out if any config can disable the access or not.

I have also tried removing all renderings but still getting same error.

[image]

Items are published properly and I have checked them in Sitecore `web` database.

Where should I look to find out the problem?

Comment: Have you tried renaming the item and checking if this works if the name does not contain `admin`?

Comment: I tired but getting same error.

Comment: there was some special permissions defined for the anonymous users for this page in the standard fields view, It is working now.